# How to access environment variables and pass to Lambda function using useDotenv: true option in serverless.yml?

Tags: environment-variables, serverless-framework

I am trying to pass environment variables to my Lambda function in serverless.yml (version 2.32.0) but I am not sure the way of doing it. The doucmentaiton: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/environment-variables/ doesn't mention how to. Right now, I am using the `useDotenv: true` option and then trying to access the environment variables by `${process.env.ENV1}` but it is not working. Below is my `serverless.yml` file:

serverless.yml

```yaml
service: service-name
frameworkVersion: "2.32.0"
useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  versionFunctions: false
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: <region>
  stage: dev
  profile: default

functions:
  function-name:
    handler: handler
    timeout: 120
    environment:
      ENV1: ${process.env.ENV1}
      ENV2: ${process.env.ENV2}
      ENV3: ${process.env.ENV3}
```

I am getting no errors or warning when I run `sls deploy` but the environment variables are not being uploaded. How would I be able to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay I got it by replacing `process.env.` with `env:`

serverless.yml:

```yaml
service: service-name
frameworkVersion: "2.32.0"
useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  versionFunctions: false
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: <region>
  stage: dev
  profile: default

functions:
  function-name:
    handler: handler
    environment:
      ENV1: ${env:ENV1}
      ENV2: ${env:ENV2}
      ENV3: ${env:ENV3}
    timeout: 120
```

Comment: Urgh, do we have to pass them manually, one-by-one ?